# How to type text into Vim's command-line without executing it?

Tags: function, vim

**My context:**
I frequently take notes in VIM.  I'd like a VIM function to type a standard-header into the command line (specifically, a timestamp such as `:sav 20180418_`) *without* executing; control would return with VIM still in command-mode (so that user could append remainder of the filename and execute).

**My fundamental difficulty:** I cannot seem to get a Vim function/macro to enter command-mode, supply text to the command line, then exit *while staying in command-mode and not executing the text supplied*.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expand()` function. For example if you are currently editing file `20180418_.txt` you can type:

```
:sav <c-r>=expand("%:r")<cr>
```

where `<c-r>=` should be typed as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>=</kbd>. <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is  `<cr>`. This will expand the text in the command line into:

```
:sav 20180418_
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible for this to be coded in a Vim-function (so I can initiate it with a key-binding)?  Rather than `expand("%:t")` (which returns nothing for me), I'd likely use `strftime("%Y%m%d_")`.  There's something basic about command-mode content in Vim functions that I seem to not understand: I tried entering `:sav <C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d_")<CR>` as the one line of a function (didn't run).

Comment: You can use a command-line map: `cnoremap 'e <c-r>=strftime("%Y%m%d_")<cr>`.  Now typing `'e` in command line will expand into `20180418_`

Comment: Thanks, that's a close-enough workaround for my purposes. :)